# Why does Australia/Brisbane (UTC+10) yield a time value less than the UTC?

Tags: php, time, timezone

Feel free to run the codes here: http://codepad.org/SAOaOABn

Code:

```
<?php

$time = time();

echo date_default_timezone_get()."\n";
echo mktime( gmdate("H", $time), gmdate("i", $time), gmdate("s", $time), gmdate("m", $time), gmdate("d", $time), gmdate("Y", $time))."\n";

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');
echo date_default_timezone_get()."\n";
echo mktime( gmdate("H", $time), gmdate("i", $time), gmdate("s", $time), gmdate("m", $time), gmdate("d", $time), gmdate("Y", $time));
```

Output:

```
UTC
1297828288
Australia/Brisbane
1297792288
```

My question is, why does Australia/Brisbane (UTC+10) yield a time value less than the UTC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're telling the computer that your timezone is UTC+10. Then when you say "please tell me the UTC time when it's 11:00 in Brisbane", you're going to get 01:00 UTC.

The `mktime` function uses local time, while `gmdate` uses UTC, so you're not going to get UTC back. If you use `date` instead of `gmdate`, you'll get the same time back.

Comment: Unix timestamp is the number of seconds elapsed since January 1, 1970 (UTC). So you are changing the timezone but not changing the time, then converting it to UTC.